# Unable to open downloaded file embedded file link in a webpage because file format or extension is not valid

Tags: html, css, django, reactjs, google-app-engine

My client has requested that I embed a link for a downloadable excel in my react/django site and unfortunately the download works whenever I run the site on my local, but after deployment you can successfully download the link, but whenever you open it, excel throws a popup that says "Excel cannot open the file 'filename' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file. I've checked the file in the directory of the build on GAE and the extension is still .xlsx, after the download I still see the .xlsx extension in my downloads folder. I've even tried to convert the excel to a pdf and embed that link, and while that still works on my local, after deployment I get "Failed to open file."

I'm not sure if this is actually related to the deployment or some of the config settings in django or react tripping me up similar to how static images need to be specified in the app.yaml. I've searched the documentation on the subject on their site here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml and nothing jumps out to me as a config I missed to resolve the issue.

The link is embedded in my site using the  tag:

```
    <p> Here is a partial list of completed projects. Download the <a href="/files/ReferenceListCopy.pdf" download>link</a> for the full list. </p>
```

I'm hoping this is something simple I've missed. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried a link to a real `.xlsx` file?  `ReferenceListCopy.pdf` is a PDF.  Does the downloaded file have a name and extension?  You have to convert PDFs before you can open in Excel.  Does it open in Acrobat?  If so, convert it to `.xlsx` in Acrobat: `Export PDF > spreadsheet > Microsoft Excel Workbook`

Comment: I started with xlsx and converted it to .pdf in an attempt to get it working. Both the xlsx and the pdf open in their respective programs whenever I download them from my local, but they give the listed error messages when downloaded from my site after it was deployed to GAE.

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the file in your `/static` directory, and serve it as a static file.  Add this to `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /static/(.*\.(xlsx|xls))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(xlsx|xls))
```

And access via: `<a href="/static/ReferenceListCopy.xlsx" download>link</a>`

If you still have trouble, try:

```
- url: /static/(.*\.xls)
  mime_type: application/vnd.ms-excel
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xls)) 

- url: /static/(.*\.xlsx)
  mime_type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.xlsx)
```

You could do the same for `pdf`s:

```
- url: /static/(.*\.pdf)
  mime_type: application/pdf
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.pdf)
```